# Serializing a C# object into a multidimensional JSON array of a specific type

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm working with Highcharts that wants data in the following format and I'm having trouble achieving it:

```
var data = [
    ["CityName", 1234],
    ["City2", 12123]
]
```

etc...

So, I'm needing this formatted like the above array and simply can't seem to achieve it.

I've seen this from JSON.NET:

```
string[,] famousCouples = new string[,]
  {
    { "Adam", "Eve" },
    { "Bonnie", "Clyde" },
    { "Donald", "Daisy" },
    { "Han", "Leia" }
  };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(famousCouples, Formatting.Indented);
// [
//   ["Adam", "Eve"],
//   ["Bonnie", "Clyde"],
//   ["Donald", "Daisy"],
//   ["Han", "Leia"]
// ]
```

That's fine for strings, but how about string and a float together? This is a requirement as one of the numbers needs to aggregate over a list and `string[,]` really isn't an ideal object to work with.

At the minute I'm using `List<Dictionary<string,float>` (this would also be the result with a custom object) and the serializer is outputting data as:

```
var data = [
   {"CityName", 1234}
]
```

etc.

I may be missing something really simple, but is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably want `object[,]`:

```
object[,] cityNames = new object[,] {
    {"CityName", 1234},
    {"City2", 12345 }
};
```

Comment: Interesting, let me have a crack at that and see if it works :) If so, it'll have saved me for today!

Comment: @ChrisDixon: The theory is sound, but we'll see if it survives contact with experimental reality. :-) (I don't have JSON.Net handy, you see.)

Comment: @ChrisDixon: Cool! I'm glad that worked! FWIW, it *doesn't* work with `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`. In what I can only consider a flat-out bug in `JavaScriptSerializer`, it outputs `["CityName", 1234, "City2", 12345]` (note that that's just one dimension). Glad JSON.Net gets it right.